# Select the items of a pivot table filter and then display it by console in C#

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, excel-interop

Something strange happens, I have a pivot table with a filter field called "CIV", what I want to do is that in each iteration, select an item from the filter.

However, when printing to the console, only the filter item appears "True" (that item is the one currently selected in the excel file), so it appears "item.Visible = true;" is not working.

```
myPivotField = (Excel.PivotField)myPivotTable.PivotFields("CIV");
int j = 0;
foreach (Excel.PivotItem item in myPivotField.PivotItems())
{
    j++;
    item.Visible = true;
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Console.WriteLine(j + " - " + item.Name + " - " + item.Visible);
}
```

In theory, all the items should appear in the console with the value "TRUE" because in each iteration I am setting them like this, however, only the first field appears in "TRUE".

I don't understand why it stopped working, in a previous execution, it did start to do so and now it doesn't anymore. Is there something wrong in the code?

My idea is that in each iteration it always starts from the first item in the filter field to the last one (despite any other than the first one being selected in the excel file).

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to work around this by iterating like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= myPivotTableField.PivotItems().Count; i++)
{
    myPivotTableField.CurrentPage = myPivotTableField.PivotItems(i).Name;
}
```